# ssh with private pem key not possible (dlopen image not found)

Tags: macos, ssh, amazon-ec2

Since this evening i can't connect to my AWS EC2 instances.
It keeps telling me the following:

```
dlopen private.pem failed: dlopen(private.pem, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:    private.pem: file too short
```

This is the output of my ssh connection:

```
'''ssh $SSHOPTS -I private.pem admin@54.213.238.233
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/evertvancauwenberg/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 53: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 54.213.238.233 [54.213.238.233] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.enter code here
dlopen private.pem failed: dlopen(private.pem, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    private.pem: file too short
debug1: identity file /Users/evertvancauwenberg/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/evertvancauwenberg/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/evertvancauwenberg/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/evertvancauwenberg/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 6f:80:22:e6:cd:c0:84:c4:1c:11:a8:bb:ee:55:2e:75
The authenticity of host '54.213.238.233 (54.213.238.233)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 6f:80:22:e6:cd:c0:84:c4:1c:11:a8:bb:ee:55:2e:75.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '54.213.238.233' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/evertvancauwenberg/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/evertvancauwenberg/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I'm working on OSX 10.9.2 
with ssh -v

OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011

```
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile]
           [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
           [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path]
           [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]
           [user@]hostname [command]
```

Comment: The option for specifying an identity file is `-i` not `-I` ... isn't it?

Comment: omg :| that i did not notice that!
Feeling very stupid now ... THNX!

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot just saved me too, being a bit rusty.  you should submit as the correct answer!

Answer (score 24):

You need to ssh using the `-i` (*identity file*) option and not `-I` (*PKCS #11 shared library*).

```
ssh -i private.pem user@ip
```

Man extract:

```
 -I pkcs11
         Specify the PKCS#11 shared library ssh should use to communicate with a
         PKCS#11 token providing the user's private RSA key.

 -i identity_file
         Selects a file from which the identity (private key) for public key
         authentication is read.  The default is ~/.ssh/id_dsa, ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa,
         ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 and ~/.ssh/id_rsa.  Identity files may also be specified
         on a per-host basis in the configuration file.  It is possible to have
         multiple -i options (and multiple identities specified
         in configuration files).  If no certificates have been explicitly specified
         by the CertificateFile directive, ssh will also try to load certificate
         information from the filename obtained by appending -cert.pub to identity
         filenames.
```

Comment: such an easy typo, thank you!

Comment: Yes, a very easy typo, and a terribly confusing error message. 

Having just read at the man page, I "knew" this wasn't my problem... except that it was (I must have hit the SHIFT key subconsciously). Thanks for saving me too!